# Set Default Value for a Unique ID Based on Multiple Rows

Tags: sql

I have a table which, after joins, gives the following values:

```
ID   Color  
1    BLACK  
1    BROWN  
1    BLUE  
2    BLUE  
2    BLACK
```

I need to write a query that sets a priority (BROWN>BLACK>BLUE) on Color so that I can return a single value by ID based on the priority. Result of this query should return:

```
ID  Color  
1   BROWN  
2   BLACK
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It will help if you post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT 
DISTINCT
Cast((CASE when t.color='BROWN' then '1' END||CASE when t.color='BLACK' then '2' END||CASE when t.color='BLUE' then '3' END) as INTEGER) as   id1, t.color 
FROM yourTable t
ORDER BY id1

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.color = (select t2.color
                 from t t2
                 where t2.id = t.id
                 order by (case when color = 'Brown' then 1
                                when color = 'Black' then 2
                                when color = 'Blue' then 3
                           end)
                );
```